# How to find and use the top features for XGBoost?

Tags: machine-learning, python, random-forest, xgboost

Suppose I have data with **X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test** given. As it is a classification problem I want to use **XGBoost**.

The issue is that there are more than 300 features.

I have found online that there are ways to find features which are important. But as I have lot of features it's causing an issue.

My current code is below. How can I modify it to say select top n ( n = 20) features and use them for training the model. I tried sorting the features based on importance but it doesn't work.

```
   import xgboost as xgb
    gbm = xgb.XGBClassifier(max_depth=3, n_estimators=300, learning_rate=0.05).fit(X_train,y_train)
    predictions = gbm.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: why selecting the important features doesn't work?

Answer (score 5):

SKLearn is friendly on this. Simply with:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
selection = SelectFromModel(gbm, threshold=0.03, prefit=True)
selected_dataset = selection.transform(X_test)
```

you will get a dataset with only the features of which the importance pass the threshold, as Numpy array. Point that the threshold is relative to the total importance, so it goes from 0 to 1.

If you want to visualize the importance, maybe to manually select the features you want, you can do like this:

```
xgb.plot_importance(booster=gbm ); plt.show()
```

Comment: Is there a way to chose the best threshold.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no automatic way. Cutting off features helps to regularize a model, avoiding over fitting, but too much cut make a bad model. So it depends on your data and on your model, so the only way of selecting a good threshold is with trials and error

Comment: @VincenzoLavorini - So even while we use classifiers like `gbm` as shown above or `random forest` etc for feature selection, do we need to select the best hyperparamters?

Comment: Or its only during model building and for feature selection it's okay to have just an estimator with default values? Upvoted as your response somehwat helped

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
results=pd.DataFrame()
results['columns']=x_data.columns
results['importances'] = clf.feature_importances_
results.sort_values(by='importances',ascending=False,inplace=True)

results[:20]
```